# Update command in database

Tags: subsonic

I found that auto-generate update command is:

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'UPDATE [Category] 
    SET Parent_Category_Id=@up_Parent_Category_Id, Index=@up_Index
  WHERE [dbo].[Category].[Id] = @0',
N'@up_Parent_Category_Id int,@up_Index int,@0 int',
@up_Parent_Category_Id=14,
@up_Index=2,
@0=16
```

I don't think that is a good command, we should put column name "Index" into []. It makes my solution brake down.

I don't know where I should report this bug (or not), so I put it in here.

FYI:

```
insert: query.Value(col.QualifiedName, hashed[key], col.DataType);  
update: query.Set(dirty.Name).EqualTo(settings[dirty.Name]);
```

I found these code line when I try to fix it myself, but ... It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a valid bug. You should create a ticket here: http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues